# How to select dataframe columns whose values follow a specific formatting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Why is the case so?

So I have sales data distributed in multiple (.xlsx) files and I am working on a parser which can extract pricing information from all files. Problem is files neither have same names for the columns (e.g. Price, USD Price, $ Price, Wholesale Price, MSRP might be one of the few column names referring to the same column), nor the order of columns is predictable. (So yeah `loc()` and `iloc()` are off the table ha!) I want to extract Product info e.g. UPC and prices. UPCs are formatted as a nominal UPC number so I know if it occurs a long integer like this, its the column I want. Secondly prices; they are formatted as $XXX.XX sp I know in which column they occur, these are the columns, I want to parse as pricing.

### What is the question?

So my question is how I can select columns based on formatting of their contents. E.g. all the columns having values like $XXX.XX formatting without knowing their names or relative positions in dataframe?

### What I have tried?

```
possible_cols_name_parts = ['MSRP', 'Price', 'USD', '$', 'Wholesale']
for col in df.columns():
    if any([col.__contains__(part) for part in possible_cols_name_parts]):
        do_usd_stuff()
```

But there are two issues:

1. This logic is based on column names and problem is not about column
   names as I mentioned which can be different and may not have these
   strings as a part of their names. But I want to filter those columns
   whose values follow this formatting: $XXX.XX.
2. Even currently it fails in case of new column names and I cannot
   adding such parts to the list of course. Plus, it would always be
   prone to leaks. In my opinion selection of columns based on content
   formatting is the ultimate solution.

Comment: There are always same format i all columns? So is possible test only first row? Or there should be different formats, e.g. in column `col` first value is `20.5` and second `$20`, third `10`... ?

Comment: Yes Format is same across the rows

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same for a while, but found this solution, which will check the **first row** with your regex and return only columns, where this regex expression return "true":

```
regex='your_regex_here'

df1 = df[df.iloc[0].str.contains(regex, na=False).index[df.iloc[0].str.contains(regex, na=False)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `regex` and joined values by `|` for regex `or`:

```
possible_cols_name_parts = ['MSRP', 'Price', 'USD', '$', 'Wholesale']
df1 = df.filter(regex='|'.join(possible_cols_name_parts))
```

Alternative:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(possible_cols_name_parts))]
```

If need all columns strating by `$`:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('$')]

#^ for start of string, escaped $ because special regex char
df2 = df.filter(regex='^\$')
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael thanks for the tip. It helps, if I stick to the current flawed logic but how to select a column whose name does not contain these parts in name but still has values which follow $XXX.XX formatting.

Comment: @Hamza - I edit answer, but not sure if understand what need.

Comment: Hey @jezrael! It is not about column names as I mentioned which can be different and may not have these strings as a part of their names. But I want to filter those columns whose values follow this formatting: $XXX.XX. Perhaps I am unclear. Will edit question to incorporate that as well

Comment: @Hamza - Can you add some sample data? input and expected output?